# How to make a word of all letters in a list? (Python)

Tags: python, list

How can I make a word from all the letters in a string?

For example:
(this is my list)

> ["h","e","l","l","o"]

And I want this as output:

> hello

Comment: use `"".join(["h","e","l","l","o"])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
"".join(["h","e","l","l","o"])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the **join** function which concatenate all the characters/substrings present in the list & return a single string.

```
name = ["h","e","l","l","o"]
concat_name = "".join(name)
print(concat_name)
```

**Output :**

```
hello
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
''.join(["h","e","l","l","o"])
```